# How can I connect to Alfresco documents through custom web application

Tags: java, ms-word, alfresco

Our java web application uses Alfresco as DMS. The application uses one single systemuser to connect to Alfresco. The application manages the access rights itself with some Business Logic.

Now what I'd like to accomplish, is to be able to use the MS Office URIs to do online editing of Word documents that live in Alfresco. So that's for example an URL that looks like ms-word:ofe|u|https://ourwebapp.com/documents/mydocument.docx
However if we open our documents like this, the user would end up being able to do stuff on Alfresco that we don't want them to do.

Because we want to keep our documents safe and secure, we don't want the users to be able to get the Alfresco documents "directly", but through our app. Opening Alfresco documents directly would mean that each individual user should get a unique Alfresco username/password and we don't have that and we don't want that because we already have lots and lots of documents living in Alfresco.

Surely there are other companies running into this problem? I.e. using their DMS with one single system user?

What I've already tried is to make REST endpoint. A Spring Filter ensures that an authorisation header with username/password is added and the request is forwarded to Alfresco. Then the response from Alfresco is passed back to the user. However this results in a document that's opened in read-only modus at best. Further more, it doesn't seem very secure to set up a connection with the user, using this system user credentials. For all I know, the user will be able to do stuff in Alfresco he isn't supposed to do. Like editing or even viewing other documents. A little bit like this:

[image]

There's very little documentation on how the ms-word protocol exactly works, maybe you can point me in the right direction? Or suggest some workarounds I might try out?

Comment: Microsoft publish loads of documentation on how the "SharePoint edit online protocol" stuff works (which is what Alfresco also implements for this), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-spo/a9173bd4-2327-41ac-8ecb-dc20e0ab7d92 for an intro to it all

Comment: Depending on Alfresco version, you either go SPP or AOS.

Answer (score 3):

For this to work using sharepoint protocol (SPP) you woud have to reimplement the whole protocol server in front of your application since you control the access. There is no free or even available SPP implementation I know of you can (re)use for this.

The Alfresco protocol server may not be an option since you can't / want mirror access control from your app into alfresco. If you get access to a system like Alfresco or Sharepoint using file protocol you will get too much access rights as you already described. By following a concept of an application user you may be locked out from Alfresco concepts for end users if you can't mirror the access logic into alfresco.

Years ago we implemented a dynamic low level access voter to up- or downgrade access inside Alfresco's node service to allow specific permissions based on types and metadata. The same way someone could implement an interface to another system to delegate permission checks based on external data but this would slow down all the systems involved dramatically.

We have a similar requirement since we access documents and data from several enterprise sources including Alfresco from our own business process product having a rule and process based access concept based on cases, processes the documents are involved in- not on folders or document's static ACLs. We use a local service installed on the client partnering with the browser app for downloading, opening and saving back documents after closing the file from a local temporay (checked out) path. Our local client has no idea from Alfresco and is authenticated only against our services using JSON Web Tokens.

So my answer is more a concept not a ready to go solution in the hope to be helpful.